# How to pass parameters to PHP script who uses $argv

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, command-line-interface, argv

I'm trying to send a request from a server to another
but the problem is that the server which will return the response is using $argv to get the data

I tried some solutions with no success

to retrieve data I tried these 3 solutions with no success, I also tried some ajax requests but always getting the same results

**from cli**

```
PHP http://[IP]/profile.php parameters // return an error Could not open input file:
```

**using file_get_contents**

```
<?php

$url = 'http://[serverIP]/profile.php';
$data = array('firstname' => 'value1', 'lastname' => 'value2');

$options = array('http' => array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => http_build_query($data)
));

$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

print_r($result); // return false
```

**using cURL**

```
<?php
$handle = curl_init();
 
$url = "http://[IP]/profile.php";
 
$postData = array(
  'firstName' => 'value1',
  'lastName'  => 'value2',
);
 
curl_setopt_array($handle,
    array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_POST       => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER     => true,
    )
);
 
$data = curl_exec($handle);
 
curl_close($handle);
 
echo $data; // return false
```

**PHP script that receives the request**

```
<?php

if (isset(count($argv)))
{
    echo count($argv);
} 
else
{
    echo "false";
}
```